# Python Pandas 0.14.0. Error with timestamp format when using dataframe.to_sql

Tags: python, sqlite, numpy, pandas, quandl

Code is pretty straight forward:

```
import Quandl
import sqlite3

myData = Quandl.get("DMDRN/AAPL_ALLFINANCIALRATIOS")

cnx = sqlite3.connect("APPL.db")
myData.to_sql('AAPL', cnx)
```

I make a call to [Quandl API](https://www.quandl.com/). It gives me a pandas dataframe. 
When I try to commit the data to a SQL table I get this error

```
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

The index is a Timestamp.

I have tried this 
1- [How to write Pandas dataframe to sqlite with Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14431646/how-to-write-pandas-dataframe-to-sqlite-with-index) 
2- Set the index to an other value + [Convert numpy.datetime64 to string object in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19502506/convert-numpy-datetime64-to-string-object-in-python)

For the first one I still get an error binding parameter 1 and 2 isn't working.

What I should do (or what's the best way) if I want to commit the dataframe to a sqlite table and keep the date as the index.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [pandas to_sql method gives error with date column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24389580/pandas-to-sql-method-gives-error-with-date-column/24403014#24403014)

The problem is that writing datetime64 values is not yet supported with a sqlite connection. With upcoming pandas 0.15, this bug will be fixed.
Writing the index is already supported (from pandas 0.14), and controllable with the `index` keyword (default of True).

You some options to solve this:

- use sqlalchemy to make the connection (you need at least 0.14 for this), as this already supports writing datetime values:

  ```
  import sqlalchemy
  engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:///APPL.db')
  myData.to_sql('AAPL', engine, index=True)
  ```
- convert the datetime index to strings (and then you can keep using sqlite connection directly). You can do this with:

  ```
  myData.index = myData.index.map(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
  ```
- use pandas development version (https://github.com/pydata/pandas)